# How to invoke WCF service through browser (Firefox)?

Tags: wcf, browser

I'm just wondering how to invoke WCF service through browser (Firefox)?

My WCF service look like this:

```
http://localhost:4249/TestService.svc
```

I've tried this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetAllPersons", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    List<Person> GetAllPersons();


public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public List<Person> GetAllPersons()
    {
        return Employees.CreateEmployees();
    }
```

And I've tried this in browser's address line:

```
http://localhost:4249/TestService/GetAllPersons
```

But, I've got the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /TestService/GetAllPersons

What I did wrong?

Here's my web.config file and you can take a look at:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="TestService.TestServiceBehavior" name="TestService.TestService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestService.ITestService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="TestService.TestServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: try mentioning .svc in URL http://localhost:4249/TestService.svc/GetAllPersons and you need to set Factory property in your svc Markup file.

Comment: I've tried that with .svc, but I don't know how to set Factory. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You cannot leave the .svc out of the URL. Right-click your .svc file in Visual Studio and pick "Browse" from the pop-up menu, then you can see the full URL of the service in your browser.

Comment: @Roy Dictus, Ok. I did. It still doesn't work. I've got white page.

Comment: Try something simpler first, to determine the root cause. For instance, add a webmethod that just returns a string rather than a list of Person objects, and see if you can execute that via the browser. BTW are you sure that your service allows HTTP GET access? Second idea: surf to http://localhost:4249/TestService.svc?wsdl to see the full contract of your service.

Comment: Mention this Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" in your SVC markup file and try.

Comment: I've tried this:

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetSomething", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
string GetSomething();

public string GetSomething()
{
  return "Hello world";
}

And I've got the same - white page.

Comment: @Mohan: My svc markup looks like this: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TestService.TestService" CodeBehind="TestService.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>. I'vew got page with the error.

Comment: @Roy Dictus, How can I check if my service allows HTTP GET?

Comment: @Roy Dictus, What should I look for in WSDL? I can't see anything useful there.

Comment: Can you post your web.config file? You probably need to enable GET there, but it will be easier to help if we can see the configuration information.

Comment: Who said anything about IIS? Please post the web.config file from the root of your WCF project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the factory changes mentioned in the comment above, you need to enable webHttpBinding in your web.config. Use this as a template, copying the contract and name details from your existing web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WHB" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AllowGet">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AllowGet" name="">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WHB" contract="" />
  </service>
</services>
```